# packed data types and assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, operating-system

I don't understand what an instruction sheet manual means when they talk of

for example

```
128-bit packed double-precision floating point
128-bit packed byte integers
128-bit packed word integers
128-bit packed doubleword integers
128-bit packed quadword integers
```

Also some instructions operate on packed data type.
Can someone please help me understand what packed data means?

Comment: In a nutshell, it means "a 128-bit wide array of a given number of these elements".

Comment: Well,can we have unpacked data?How is the unpacked data layered out?

Comment: There is also scalar data, where only a single item is operated on. The instruction set reference clearly details how each instruction operates.